# Easy Jaydata example fails

Tags: javascript, odata, jaydata

I am following this tutorial:

http://jaydata.org/tutorials/creating-a-stand-alone-web-application

So after including this:

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="jaydata-1.5.5-rc/jaydata.js"></script>
```

I am trying to run this sample code (I copied and pasted that):

```
$data.Entity.extend("$org.types.Department", {
    Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
    Name: { type: "string", required: true },
    Address: { type: "string" },
    Employees: { type: "Array", elementType: "$org.types.Employee", inverseProperty: "Department" }
});
alert($data.Entity.Department);
$data.Entity.extend("$org.types.Employee", {
    Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
    FirstName: { type: "string", required: true },
    LastName: { type: "string", required: true },
    Department: { type: "$org.types.Department", inverseProperty: "Employees" }
});

$data.EntityContext.extend("$org.types.OrgContext", {
    Department: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: $org.types.Department },
    Employee: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: $org.types.Employee }
});
```

But in the Browser I get the error message, that "$org.types.Department" is not defined. 
This is driving me crazy, because I am doing exactly what the easy tutorial says.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

JayData 1.5.x stopped using global variables, so when you define a new type, put it in a variable and reference that in the elementType.

```
var departmentType = $data.Entity.extend("$org.types.Department", ...
var employeeType = $data.Entity.extend("$org.types.Employee", ...

$data.EntityContext.extend("$org.types.OrgContext", {
    Department: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: departmentType  },
    Employee: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: employeeType }
});
```